# Could not format the Namenode in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-14.04, giraph, namenode

While formatting namenode by executing the command " bin/hadoop namenode -format " i get this error:

hduser@ubuntu:~/hadoop/bin$ ./hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Error : Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

Comment: Do you export HADOOP_HOME correctly in your ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 1):

try removing all hadoop temp data 
 rm -Rf /app/hadoop/tmp/*
then try again formatting

Answer (score 0):

It means that you should not use `hadoop namenode -format` but `hdfs namenode -format` instead, since it has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work?

```
 ~/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format
```